# Surjectivity of $H_1(X) \to H_1(X,A)$ for pathwise connected $A$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $A$ is a pathwise connected subspace of an arbitrary topological space $X$.
The canonical morphism $H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is then injective, which in turn implies (by the long exact sequence associated to the situation) that the canonical morphism $ H_1(X)\to H_1(X,A)$ is surjective.
This is easy, clear and rigorous but I would like to know if there is a direct "geometric" proof of that surjectivity.

Answer (score 2):

$H_1(X,A)$ is generated by classes $[y]$ which can be represented by $y:[0,1]\to X$ with $y(0),\;y(1)\in A$. Since $A$ is path connected, let $z:[0,1]\to A$ be a path connecting $y(0)$ and $y(1)$. Then $[x]\in H_1(X)$ represented by a cycle $x:[0,1]\to X$, which is defined as a concantenation $y*z^{-1}$, maps to $[y]\in H_1(X,A)$.